# MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:27017

Tags: node.js, mongodb, docker, docker-compose

I was trying to integrate a mongodb for my NodeJS application.
This is a dockerized project and for some sort of reason, my NodeJS app cannot connect to my mongo container. First line of error is:

```
MongoNetworkError: failed to connect to server [mongo:27017] on first connect [MongoNetworkError: connect ECONNREFUSED 172.18.0.2:27017]
```

I have browsed through a lot of tutorial thinking that my logic or my configurations were not correct, but to no avail. It just keeps on giving me the same error. I've been stuck here for quite a few days.

I then tried to do this:

https://github.com/bradtraversy/docker-node-mongo from this tutorial https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hP77Rua1E0c

to see if my project is the only one that is not functional, but then to my surprise, it also gave me the same error after building the containers, even though on his tutorial, it was seamless. Now, I am clueless to what's really wrong with this. I believe that this is no longer due to my configurations, but might be because of the docker, or my OS, or something. I don't know. Did someone experience this already? Please help.

I'm attaching these data since it might help:

- Docker version: **Docker version 19.03.11, build 42e35e61f3**
- OS: **Ubuntu 20.04 LTS (Focal Fossa)**
- docker-compose version 1.25.0, build unknown

Comment: The error ECONNREFUSED is returned by the operation system of the machine at 172.18.0.2 because there is no process listening on 27017.

Comment: I ran docker exec inside the mongo container and it's running fine. @Joe